# Renaming URL in php not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm writing this:

```
RewriteRule ^title$  articles.php?&=stop [QSA,L,N,S=15]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !stop 
RewriteRule articles.php? http://mysite.com/pages/title [r=301,L,nc]
```

in order rename from `pages/title?id_article=2` to `pages/title`

but it doesn't work.
Any advice please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: changing pages/title?id_article=2  to pages/title/2  or to pages/title itself ??

Comment: pages/title itself  ... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it with PHP, following is the script:

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$url = explode('?', $url);

if(!empty($url[1])) 
{
header("Location: http://".$url[0]);
}
?>
```

Comment: I put a wrong title. Better: Renaming PHP URLs with HTACCESS. But thank you for answer. I bet it's a good one for my question in the title.

Comment: But any ideas for my real question?

Comment: @duracell sorry... no idea oh htaccess